# JQuery Numeral Slider Error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a JQuery slider to allow site members to edit a search radius and automatically input the value into a hidden field.  The code I'm using works well but it displays too many numbers after the . in the input field.  I've created a Fiddle to better display this.  Does anyone know how to prevent the large amount of numbers in the input field?

Here is my code & JSFiddle:

```
<div class="sectionInner">
                                        <input type="text" data-slider="true" data-slider-range="4,50">
                                        <div class="sliderLabel">Find Events Within&nbsp;</div>
                                        <div class="sliderLabel output"></div>
                                        <div class="sliderLabel">&nbsp;Miles of <?php echo $yourpostcode; ?></div>
                                        <div class="sliderLabel"><a id="radButton">Find Them</a></div>
                                        <form id="radForm" method="post" action="events.php?type=rad&from=<?php echo $from; ?>">
                                            <input type="hidden" id="radSearch" name="var" />
                                        </form>
                                    </div>

$("[data-slider]")
.bind("slider:ready slider:changed", function (event, data) {
  $(this)
    .nextAll(".output:first")
    .html(data.value.toFixed(0));
    var slider = $(this).val();
    $('#radSearch').val(slider);
});
```

JS = http://jsfiddle.net/bxbzc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `slider` variable to be an integer like so

```
var slider = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bxbzc/1/

Comment: Thank You, That works perfectly - However I'm noticing that as I add the value on the Slider, the value in the Input field is slightly behind, do you know of any reasons why that might be?

Comment: Yes, you are using the slider:changed event which is updated when you 'stop' dragging

Comment: Ah right. It's not all that important but is thare another variable that can be used so that it matches exactly?

Comment: I believe you want to use bind('slider:slide') edit: Nevermind, that doesn't work. Your only option may be the slider:changed method

Comment: Thanks, but doing that stops the numeral calculation altogether

Comment: Yep, I noticed once I actually tested it. I believe the 'changed' event that you're using is the one you want

Comment: No, that is still having the same effect

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42813/discussion-between-hacknightly-and-user2737457)